# Excel - average a range of column as defined by second column and another condition

Tags: r, excel, matlab

I have a very large table of data consisting of 3 columns I'm interested in here.

The 1st column identifies the time (column C); these values repeat (12 per tenth of a second):

03:30.8

03:30.8

03:30.8

03:30.8

03:30.8

03:30.8

03:30.9

03:30.9

03:30.9

03:30.9

03:30.9

The 2nd column gives me the data I am interested in (numerical, pupil dilation, dependent variable -- Column J) example:

3.782994

3.789125

3.784591

3.786793

3.789103

3.786221

3.780111

3.783228

3.781195

3.775694

The 3rd column consists of text strings identifying the video stimulus for that given measurement (column 2) at that given time (column 1). The stimulus name column is AA. example:

No media

No media

No media

Happy.avi

Happy.avi

Happy.avi

Happy.avi

Happy.avi

Happy.avi

Happy.avi

Happy.avi

Happy.avi

There will be blank rows in the table occasionally.

I need to average the pupil dilation data (column C) 
for a given stimulus ("Happy" -- column AA) 
but 2 seconds after it starts, which will be  241 cells/rows down from the first observation for that stimulus, and the average will involve thousands of cells of data.

I would like to use Excel (suggestions for R and MATLAB also welcome).

Many thanks for reading and considering this!

Comment: Please show us what the data and the expected output is supposed to look like.

Comment: I'm assuming you want to average on column J not C right? In excel you will need to use `averageif` or `averageifs`. If you should be able to get that 2 second delay using `offset`. In MATLAB you would use `accumarray`

Comment: Thanks to you both -- yes, the visual would be nice but only have a spreadsheet and no reputation (just joined) so I'm prevented from posting a pic.  I just edited the post to give you a better idea of what the data looks like.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an Excel solution using `AVERAGEIF`, `OFFSET` and `COUNTA`:

[image: Excel sheet]

So the formula used is

```
=AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(C2,0,0,COUNTA(C:C)-1),"="&E4,OFFSET(B2,2,0,COUNTA(C:C)-1))
```

where column `A` is time, column `B` is data and column `C` is stimulus and assuming a header row (i.e. the data all starts on row 2). Note that the `COUNTA` is used to define the `OFFSET` height and so the `-1` is to account for my single header row, you might need to adjust this for your sheet.

Comment: That's a thing of beauty.  The average value looks to be a bit off when I change the formula to accomodate the structure of the spreadsheet -- the data starts on the 25th row so I used: =AVERAGEIF(OFFSET(AA25,0,0,COUNTA(AA:AA)-24),"="&E4,OFFSET(J25,240,0,COUNTA(AA:AA)-24))

Comment: The average is a tad high, 3.18716 instead of 3.1686; there are 233 cells in the range that have the text "no data" but Excel should automatically exclude those from the average, right? Do you see any problems with the changes I made or have any ideas about what might be wrong?  Looks like the range is slightly off, but the reference cells look ok.

Comment: You might have problems using `COUNTA` if you have empty cells in your first 24 rows. You will need to find a way to dynamically control the height specified in the `OFFSET` function which will be specific to your sheet. It might be worth your while to refactor your workbook though so that this data is on the second row of some other worksheet...